# Achievements dropdown no longer updating

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

The achievements dropdown got stuck today somewhere between 07:15 UTC and 07:45 UTC; it is no longer showing me my latest updates (last included entry was logged at 07:14:28Z, next new update not included in the box was at 07:46:02Z):

[image: Stuck at +71]

Compared to my [Stack Overflow reputation history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation):

[image]

I earned a +10 on Meta.SE too, and possibly got upvotes or badges on other sites too that were not included.

I even tried to go directly to the AJAX endpoint for the box:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements?_=1490864082335
```

I incremented the cache-breaker number and forced reloads, but it remains stuck at +71.

Comment: If you interested, please check this issue too https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293106/profile-not-showing-reputation-correctly-for-network-accounts

Comment: @Stijn: It contains a little more detail about timing. I'll leave it up as a dupe, in case there is a bit more info that the devs can use to narrow this down.